# -replace in powershell changing data but not saving it

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0

```
$xmlFilePath = 'Desktop\original.xml'
$xmlfile = get-content $xmlFilePath
$xmlfile -Replace 'box','boxes'
```

the original.xml contain some data and i want to replace "boxes" value in xml file with 'box'. power shell gives output as expected but doesn't change the actual file original.xml. I get the changed output in power shell but when i view the file the desktop the file doesn't have the changes.

Comment: You're performing an operation on lines of text _in memory_ only; pipe to `Set-Content`, for instance, to save the results back to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7) to read a file's contents into memory, apply the string replacements, and then pass the contents through the pipeline to [Set-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-7).

```
$xmlFilePath = 'Desktop\original.xml'
(Get-Content $xmlFilePath) -replace 'box','boxes' | Set-Content $xmlFilePath
```

The use of `()` around the `Get-Content` command is necessary to prevent the parser from interpreting `-replace` as a parameter.

Note that if you want to read in a file's contents as a single string, you can use the `-Raw` switch on `Get-Content`. Not using `-Raw` could add extra new line characters.

Answer (score 1):

you only changing the value in memory. you have to output that variable to the original .xml file again. here's how:

```
$xmlFilePath = 'Desktop\original.xml'
$xmlfile = get-content $xmlFilePath
$xmlfile = $xmlfile -Replace 'box','boxes'
$xmlfile | Out-File $xmlFilePath
```